# Possible to boot OS originally installed MBR after converting disk to GPT?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have Windows 10 and 7 on my hard disk. I installed Windows 10 on a partition on the disk, GPT, converted the disk to MBR, installed Windows 7 on another partition, then converted the disk back to GPT. After some fixing Windows 10 boots but Windows 7 is not detected at all even when switching to legacy mode. Any way to make Windows 7 run on GPT?

Comment: Yes; However, the only way to make a switch like this on Windows 7 is to make the change from within Windows before you make the change.  In it's current state your likely out of luck with regards to recovering the Windows 7 installation.  It's also unclear the reason you converted from GPT to MBR and then back to GPT since Windows 7 could have simply have been installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Would a VM running Windows 7 be usable, instead? https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/win7-virtual-machine.html , for example